# Differentiate between NULL and 0

Tags: php, if-statement, null

sorry this seems to be a repeated question but it confused to why I can't get a drop-down box to differentiate between null and 0.

I have a drop-down box with some PHP which select a value from a database and assigns it to `$user`. The default value is null, but I then want to change it to a 0 or 2 (its for number of tickets, so null is I haven't assigned any, 0 is I don't want to give them any, and 2 is they get 2). Basically the code below doesn't distinguish between null and 0 and based on other posts I read I feel it should but obviously I'm missing something.

```
<option value="" <?php if( is_null($user)){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Not Set</option>
<option value="0" <?php if($user === 0){ echo 'selected'; }?>>0</option>
<option value="2" <?php if($user === 2){ echo 'selected'; }?>>2</option>
```

I have also tried

```
<option value="" <?php if($user === NULL){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Not Set</option>
<option value="0" <?php if($user === 0){ echo 'selected'; }?>>0</option>
<option value="2" <?php if($user === 2){ echo 'selected'; }?>>2</option>
```

and

```
<option value="" <?php if($user === ''){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Not Set</option>
<option value="0" <?php if($user === 0){ echo 'selected'; }?>>0</option>
<option value="2" <?php if($user === 2){ echo 'selected'; }?>>2</option>
```

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
var_dump($user) = string(1) "0"
```

This is the same where `$user = NULL` and `$user = 0`

on my local xampp  `var_dump($user)=int(0)` and `var_dump($user)=NULL` the same code is acting different on the live version.

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump($user)` please, just so we know what we are dealing with

Comment: As a general rule, `NULL` is used to denote a value that is not known, not available (yet) or not applicable. It is definitely different than `0`; `0` is a known value that denotes the absence of whatever items it counts. Using `0` instead of `NULL` is a logic error.

Comment: `$user` is a string `"0"` there for comparing with `0` using `===` will not work. `===` compares type as well as value. **They are of different types**

Comment: Then check your schema

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by schema, shall i open a new question regarding my live server returning as string while local returns and int?